# What exactly does a Regex created with Regex.fromLiteral() match?

Tags: regex, kotlin

I've created a very simple match-all Regex with `Regex.fromLiteral(".*")`.

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/from-literal.html#kotlin.text.Regex.Companion$fromLiteral(kotlin.String)/literal): "Returns a literal regex for the specified literal string."

But I don't really get what "for the specified literal string" is supposed to mean.

Consider this example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val regex1 = ".*".toRegex()
    val regex2 = Regex.fromLiteral(".*")
    println("regex1 matches abc: " + regex1.matches("abc"))
    println("regex2 matches abc: " + regex2.matches("abc"))
    println("regex2 matches .* : " + regex2.matches(".*"))  
}
```

Output:

```
regex1 matches abc: true
regex2 matches abc: false
regex2 matches .* : true
```

so apparently (and contrary to my expectations), `Regex.fromLiteral()` and `String.toRegex()` behave completely different (I've tried dozens of different arguments to `regex2.matches()` - the only one that returned true was `.*`)

Does this mean that a Regex created with `Regex.fromLiteral()` always matches only the *exact string* it was created with?

If yes, what are possible use cases for such a Regex? (I can't think of any scenario where that would be useful)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does indeed create a regex that matches the literal characters in the `String`. This is handy when you're trying to match symbols that would be interpreted in a regex - you don't have to escape them this way.

For example, if you're looking for strings that contain `.*[](1)?[2]`, you could do the following:

```
val regex = Regex.fromLiteral(".*[](1)?[2]")

regex.containsMatchIn("foo")                  // false
regex.containsMatchIn("abc.*[](1)?[2]abc")    // true
```

Of course you can do almost anything you can do with a `Regex` with just regular `String` methods too.

```
val literal = ".*[](1)?[2]"
literal == "foo"                       // equality checks
literal in "abc.*[](1)?[2]abc"         // containment checks
"some string".replace(literal, "new")  // replacements
```

But sometimes you need a `Regex` instance as a parameter, so the `fromLiteral` method can be used in those cases. Performance of these different operations for different inputs could also be interesting for some use cases.

Comment: "Sometimes you need a Regex instance as a parameter" - true, hadn't thought of that scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The [`Regex.fromLiteral()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/from-literal.html) instantiates a regex object while escaping the special regex metacharacters. The pattern you get is actually `\.\*`, and since you used `matches()` that requires a full string match, you can only match a `.*` string with it (with `find()` you could match it anywhere inside a string).

See the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6e8f227121470cb7c2709b7b053240d0a6c203c1/js/js.libraries/src/core/regex.kt#L159):

> `public fun fromLiteral(literal: String): Regex = Regex(escape(literal))`