# positive lookbehind in kotlin doesn't work in match

Tags: regex, kotlin, lookbehind

I'm iterating on this file:

```
[INFO] com.demo:communication:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.cellwize.optserver:optserver-admin:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

I want to remove all the prefix on every line: "[INFO] " / "[INFO] +- " / "[INFO] |  |  - " etc

I'm using this function I wrote on every line in the file:

```
private fun extractDependency(raw: String): Dependency {
    val uniqueDependencyRegex = Regex.fromLiteral("(?<=\\+- ).*")
    val duplicateDependencyRegex = Regex.fromLiteral("(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")
    val projectRegex = Regex.fromLiteral("(?<=\\[INFO\\] ).*")
when {
    uniqueDependencyRegex matches raw -> {
        val matchResult = uniqueDependencyRegex.matchEntire(raw)
        println(matchResult)
    }
    duplicateDependencyRegex matches raw -> {
        val matchResult = duplicateDependencyRegex.matchEntire(raw)
        println(matchResult)
    }
    projectRegex matches raw -> {
        val matchResult = projectRegex.matchEntire(raw)
        println(matchResult)
    }
    else -> {
        //TODO - throw exception
    }
}

return Dependency("test", "test", "test", "test")
}
```

I'm expecting it to work after I tested the regular expressions:

First Condition

Second Condition

Third Condition

The result I want is:

```
com.demo:communication:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT
com.cellwize.optserver:optserver-admin:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile - omitted for duplicate
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.7:compile
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile - omitted for duplicate
```

Comment: Perhaps like this `^\[INFO\][| +\\(-]+|\)$` https://regex101.com/r/gpOO3D/1

Comment: Do not use `Regex.fromLiteral`. Use just `Regex`. `Regex("(?<=\\+- ).*")` or `"(?<=\\+- ).*".toRegex()` or `"""(?<=\+- ).*""".toRegex()`

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035889/3832970) about `Regex.fromLiteral`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either match `[INFO]` followed by a character class that will match any of the listed characters `[| +\\(-]`,  or match `)` at the end of the string.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^\[INFO\][| +\\(-]+|\)$
```

With double escaped backslashes

```
^\\[INFO\\][| +\\\\(-]+|\\)$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gpOO3D/1/)

---

A bit more precise pattern could be repeatedly matching any of the occurring patterns like  `|` or  `+-` or  `\-` and capture the content in group 1 between optional parenthesis. Then use the group in the replacement.

```
^\[INFO\](?:(?: +(?:\||\+-|\\-))+)? +\(?(.*?)\)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bhs0p0/1)

Comment: your regex with removing fromLiteral function worked for me, thanks!